# Crystal report Cross-Tab order by another column

Tags: crystal-reports

I've made a crosstab in crystal report like below:

[image]

However, as you can see, the ordering is weirld (i.e. the correct one should be like below:)

[image]

And the ordering is stored in another field called order, I took a look in the crystal report's cross-tab expert sorting option, it doesn't allow me to order by another column, it only allows me to sort either ascending or descending, how can I set the ordering by another column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Crosstab's` sorting is based on the rows order, if you want to sort it in your on you have to add some extra rows and have to `suppress` `subtotal` and `Label` in `Customize Style` of `Crosstab Expert`

---

**Example:**
If you have **3 rows**`(A,B,C)` to **display** and you have to **sort** it in order like `B,C,A` then you have to **add** `2` **new rows**`(B,C)` now your `Crosstab` looks like `(B,C,A,B,C)` now you have to **suppress** `Rows B and C` you meet your both requirements for `sorting and display order`

---

But This `solution` have some **limitations** like 
if you want to export the report in **Excel** then it will add **extra cells** in grand total.
otherwise you are **good to go**.

---

**Example:**
If you have 3 rows(A,B,C) to display and you added one row and you suppress it to solve your sorting issue then in `Excel` its grand total looks like

```html
A            B            C
a            1            3    
b            2            2
---------------------------
Total:                    3            5
```

Comment: Though this question is a bit old... I remember I used this method to solve this problem :)

Comment: Do you have some solution for mentioned excel export issue because so many people asked me about this and i was always blank.

Comment: Currently I would fetch dataset and create a function for exporting to excel

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can not sort on another column. You must use any of one column as a header.

In Crystal report, sorting happened based on header column's value (That's why you see as per alphabetic).

I also face this issue and how I solved, that I am explain. You have to use a formula which have order, but either hide it or use a value like in this link.

https://scn.sap.com/thread/3341846

Second option as per this link. (I think first you check this)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/493334/Custom-sorting-for-Crystal-Report-Cross-Tab

https://scn.sap.com/thread/1172741

Comment: I took a look at the article before, but I can't use that formula, since the columns are stored and generated from the database, the user might add or remove or re-order columns, so the ordering is stored in database..

Comment: Yes, but you have to change order in crystal report as explain in codeproject link and that's I recommend that link

Answer (score 1):

open `crosstab expert`, highlight the column that you want to reorder, go to `Group Options` and select `in specified order`. This will open another tab where you will have your available values listed there. Using the arrows on the right side you can move up or down your values and accommodate them in the order you want them to be displayed.

Comment: I've took a look at that, but the problem is, the ordering is stored in database, so I can't hardcode the order, I have to order by another column named order...

Answer (score 1):

Simple way would be take order column from stored procedure to cross tab and set the order according to that column.

Then supress the order column and reduce the width of that column to minimum pixel so that it doesn't appear in cross tab.

Answer (score 0):

Make the field you want to sort by a group field and hide it.  To hide it, in the Crosstab Expert > Customize Style dialog select this group then use the Group Options area to Suppress Subtotal and Supress Label.  Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the order field as the grouping column and change the label for said column to show the actual sizes. The labels can be changed in `Crosstab Expert`, `Grouping Options` and then the tab `Options`.